# Broken images in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with my images, which started when I changed a part of my code in view.p (API)

from:

```
    class PostListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

to:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def PostListView(request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    username = request.GET.get('username')
    if username != None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(author__username__iexact=username)
    serializer = PostSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
```

I did this because I wanted to pass "username" into it and I dont know how to do that using APIView, so i used this, but then my images are broken and i notice with the APIView, the images url starts from "127.0.0.1/8000/..." but with this new view the url is "localhost/...." which i think is the problem.

How do i go about it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `request` to `PostSerializer`'s context

For ex:

```
serializer = PostSerializer(queryset, many=True, context = {'request':request})
```